# Where can I find all the methods that I can call on an Ansible variable

Tags: ansible

Here is a simple `Ansible` playbook:

```
- name: this command prints FAILED when it fails
  command: /usr/bin/example-command -x -y -z
  register: command_result
  failed_when: "'FAILED' in command_result.stderr"
```

Now, I know variable `command_result` has a method called `stderr` but how can I get a list of all methods?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `debug` to dump the variable:

```
- name: this command prints FAILED when it fails
  command: /usr/bin/example-command -x -y -z
  register: command_result
  failed_when: "'FAILED' in command_result.stderr"
- name: dump command_result
  debug: var=command_result
```

This will output something like:

```
TASK: [dump command_result] **************************************************************
ok: [hostname] => {
    "command_result": {
        "changed": false,
        "cmd": "/usr/bin/example-command -x -y -z",
        "delta": "0:00:00.018233",
        "end": "2015-05-07 09:33:08.444674",
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": "/usr/bin/example-command -x -y -z",
            "module_name": "command"
        },
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2015-05-07 09:33:08.426441",
        "stderr": "",
        "stdout": "whatever",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "whatever"
        ],
        "warnings": []
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that certainly helped but when I tried a different variable `ansible_hostname` it does not have any methods, so that mean it is possible this variable only has a subset of all the possible methods, do you agree ? I hope there is a document list all the methods, like an API document.

Comment: Things like `ansible_hostname` are *facts* which are discovered in the first step of running a playbook. You can see what facts exist about a host (and  the structure of the information) by running `ansible hostname -m setup`

Comment: Yes I understand, I am trying to say that it is possible some variables does not have a `cmd` method and some variables have others methods. How do I find out them? I would thought there is a document for this but did not find it.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Ansible are basically strings intepreted by [Jinja2 template engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/).  Read [the language reference](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#variables) for template variable details.  Jinja2's built-in types (`string`, `sequence`, `mapping`, etc.) resembles their counterpart in Python (`str`, `list`, `dict`, etc.) and have many common attributes and methods (callable attributes), but they are not all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this "variable.stderr" is not a method, but a variable... In Ansible you don't deal with "methods" directly, as it is not a true programming language. The best source to learn, as always is the official docs for ansible, there the modules are pretty well covered.